# Keras fitting LSTM getting slower in loop

Tags: python, loops, keras, slowdown

I have a simple loop which in every iteration creates an LSTM (with the same parameters) and fit it to the same data.
The problem is that it takes more and more time during itterations.

```
batch_size = 10
optimizer = optimizers.adam(lr=0.001)
number_unites = 20

for counter_temp in range(1,100):
    t0 = time.time()

    model = None
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=number_unites, batch_input_shape=(None, batch_size, 1), return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(1))


    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_train_val, y_train_val), verbose=0)

    print(time.time()-t0)
```

Comment: It's because you're creating more and more models in Keras's graph. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks @DanielMöller.
Actually, I am new in using Keras. How can I solve this?
Assume, I want to check the difference in the results of different initialization.
How can I remove "Keras's graph" at the beginning of each iteration?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to DanielMöller, it is solved.
I used keras.backend.clear_session() to remove  "Keras's graph".

from keras.backend import clear_session

clear_session()